# Polar coordinates of vertices of a hexagonal grid?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polar-coordinates, hexagonal-tiles

Is it possible to parameterize a hexagonal grid in polar plane?

[image]

In other words, is it possible to find polar coordinates of the centers of every hexagon packed in a hexagonal grid? The central hexagon is marked by a blue circle, and its polar coordinates is (0, 0)/

Comment: Yes, it is. But you won't get integer coordinates easily. At least not with actual polar coordinates.

Comment: For future reference: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centers are found every 60° and at distance twice inscribed radius. Compute the coordinates of the closest centers at 0° and 60° and every other center is obtained as a linear combination with integer coefficients.

```
2u + v, √3 v
```

Then convert to polar coordinates

```
r= 2√[u² + uv + v²]
tan Θ = √3 v / (2u + v)
```